# angularjs typescript error in visual studio

Tags: angularjs, typescript

h-ii every-body.

I install the angularjs.typescript and jquery.typescript from nuget package. But everything give error in VStudio as attached image.

what is the problem. 
My VS is 2013 U4 and update every extension and plugin.

What is the problem ?

```
Install-Package angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
Install-Package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
```

[image]

all.ts

```
reference path="../../scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
reference path="../../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
```

[image]

[image]

i tested all module system properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution :)

i dint't install the TypeScript 1.4 for VS2013. Fck my mind :D

after installed problem solved.

TypeScript 1.4 for Visual Studio 2013

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304

Answer (score 1):

Disable resharper and wait for a resharper update for TS 1.4. Or use an older definition file that works for TS 1.3.